# Prove that $(L^R)^* = (L^*)^R$

Tags: formal-languages

> Prove that $(L^R)^* = (L^*)^R$ for all languages $L$.

My attempt: Suppose $w \in (L^R)^*$. So, $w = w_1\dots w_l$, for some $w_1, \dots , w_l \in L^R$. Since $w^R \in L$, then $w^R = w_l\dots w_1$, for some $w_l, \dots , w_1 \in L^*$. Therefore, $(L^R)^* \subseteq (L^*)^R$.

Honestly, I don't know how to proceed onwards, because this part doesn't sound right. I feel like I messed up with those symbols as this topic is really abstract. Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your formula for $w^R$ is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $w \in (L^R)^*$, then $w = w_1 \ldots w_\ell$ for some $w_1,\ldots,w_\ell \in L^R$. Hence $w_1^R,\ldots,w_\ell^R \in L$, and so $w_\ell^R \ldots w_1^R \in L^*$. This shows that $w = (w_\ell^R \ldots w_1^R)^R \in (L^*)^R$.

Similarly, if $w \in (L^*)^R$ then $w = x^R$ for $x \in L^*$. Since $x \in L^*$, $x = x_1 \ldots x_\ell$ for some $x_1,\ldots,x_\ell \in L$. Then $x_1^R,\ldots,x_\ell^R \in L^R$, and so $w = (x_1 \ldots x_\ell)^R = x_\ell^R \ldots x_1^R \in (L^R)^*$.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:**

First of all, we prove  that
$$\forall n\geq 0\hspace{6pt}(L_1\cup L_2)^R=(L_1^R\cup L_2^R).$$

First  we should show that all strings in $S= (L_1\cup L_2)^R$ are in $S'=(L_1^R\cup L_2^R)$, and all strings in $S'=(L_1^R\cup L_2^R)$  are in $S= (L_1\cup L_2)^R$. Assume $s\in S $ then  $s^R\in (L_1\cup L_2)$, hence $s\in (L_1^R\cup L_2^R)$, assume $s\in S' $ then  $s^R\in (L_1\cup L_2)$, hence $s\in (L_1\cup L_2)^R$. Therefore
$$\forall n\geq 0\hspace{6pt}(L_1\cup L_2)^R=(L_1^R\cup L_2^R).$$

We can show that
$$(L^R)^n = (L^n)^R$$
By definition of [Kleene  star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star) $$(L^R)^0\cup  (L^R)^1\cup(L^R)^2\cup\dots=(L^0\cup L^1\cup L^2\cup\dots)^R$$

By applying former part
$$(L^R)^0\cup  (L^R)^1\cup(L^R)^2\cup\dots=(L^0\cup L^1\cup L^2\cup\dots)^R$$
$$=(L^0)^R\cup (L^1)^R\cup (L^2)^R\cup\dots$$

We should show that $\forall k\geq 0 \hspace{6pt}(L^R)^k=(L^k)^R$.

By Induction:

The basis $k=0$ is

$$(L^R)^k=(L^k)^R=\lambda.$$
For induction hypothesis, suppose $$\forall k\leq n\hspace{6pt}(L^R)^k=(L^k)^R.$$
Consequently, for induction step, when $k=n+1$
$$(L^R)^{n+1}=(L^{n+1})^{R}$$
$$\implies (L^R)^{n}\cdot L^R=(L^n\cdot L)^R$$
$$\implies (L^R)^{n}\cdot L^R=(L^n)^R\cdot L^R$$

Hence the last result, follow the induction hypothesis. So statement $$(L^R)^n = (L^n)^R$$ holds for any $n$.